# How to detect application terminate in kernel extension, Mac OS X

Tags: macos, kernel, signals, exit

I am looking for an approach to detect application quit (e.g. cmd-q) in kernel space for processing in a network kernel extension.

More precisely:
While a process (e.g. terminal ping) is held in an IOLockSleep(... THREAD_ABORTSAFE), ctrl-c is able to release the lock.
Asking the proc_issignal(), it responses the sigmask(SIGINT).

Now I am looking for a way to detect another process quit, e.g. firefox (menu bar: Application quit (cmd-q)).

Here is what I tried:

```
#define FLAG(X) ((dispatch_source_get_data(src) & DISPATCH_PROC_##X) ? #X" " : "")

struct ProcessInfo {
    int pid;
    dispatch_source_t source;
};

// function called back on event
void process_termination_event(struct ProcessInfo* procinfo) {
    dispatch_source_t src = procinfo->source;
    printf("process_termination_event: %d \n", procinfo->pid);
    printf("flags: %s%s\n", FLAG(EXIT), FLAG(SIGNAL));
    dispatch_source_cancel(procinfo->source);
}

// function called back when the dispatch source is cancelled
void process_termination_finalize(struct ProcessInfo* procinfo) {
    printf("process_termination_finalize: %d \n", procinfo->pid);
    dispatch_release(procinfo->source);
}

// Monitor a process by pid, for termination
void MonitorTermination(int pid) {
    struct ProcessInfo* procinfo = (struct ProcessInfo*)malloc(sizeof(struct ProcessInfo));

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_source_t dsp = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_PROC, pid, DISPATCH_PROC_EXIT|DISPATCH_PROC_SIGNAL, queue);

    procinfo->pid = pid;
    procinfo->source = dsp;

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f(procinfo->source, (dispatch_function_t)process_termination_event);
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler_f(procinfo->source, (dispatch_function_t)process_termination_finalize);
    dispatch_set_context(procinfo->source, procinfo);
    dispatch_resume(procinfo->source);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        pid_t pid = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("MonitorTermination: %d\n", pid);
        fflush(stdout);

        MonitorTermination(pid);
    }

    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```

The process_termination_event will not invoke after cmd-q as explained above. Even after force quit.

The process itself is held in a loop within the network kernel extension function:

```
errno_t KEXT::data_out(void *cookie, socket_t so, const struct sockaddr *to, mbuf_t *data, mbuf_t *control, sflt_data_flag_t flags)
{
    // at this point I would like to detect the app quit/termination signal.
    while(PROCESS_IS_NOT_TEMINATING); // <-- pseudo code, actually held with IOLockSleep...
    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the way you've been thinking, but if you're in the kernel space, then I assume you're writing a kernel extension (kext). With a kernel extension, you can [monitor Vnodes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SUBSECTION11) for executing applications. You may be able to use the File Scope instead.

In conjunction with a user-level application (daemon), the kext notifies the daemon that a process has begun execution and then monitors the termination of the launched application from the user-level daemon, using [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) functions. If required, the user-application can notify the kext of the terminated app.

To monitor the termination from a user-level application, you can do something like this when you're notified of an application being executed: -

```
// pid and path provided from vNode scope kext...
void UserLevelApp::MonitorProcessTermination(int pid, const QString &path)
{    
    ProcessInfo* procinfo = new ProcessInfo;

    procinfo->pid = pid;
    procinfo->path = path;
    procinfo->context = this;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_source_t dsp = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_PROC, pid, DISPATCH_PROC_EXIT, queue);

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f(dsp, (dispatch_function_t)process_termination_event);
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler_f(dsp,  (dispatch_function_t)process_termination_finalize);

    procinfo->source = dsp;
    dispatch_set_context(dsp, procinfo);

    dispatch_resume(dsp);
}

// app terminated call-back function
void UserLevelApp::process_termination_event(struct ProcessInfo* procinfo)
{
    dispatch_source_cancel(procinfo->source);

    // example of how to use the context to call a class function
    procinfo->context->SomeClassFunction(procinfo->pid, procinfo->path);

    qDebug("App Terminated: %d, %s\n", procinfo->pid, procinfo->path.toUtf8().data());
}

// finalize callback function
void UserLevelApp::process_termination_finalize(struct ProcessInfo* procinfo)
{
   dispatch_release(procinfo->source);
   delete procinfo;
}
```

So each launched application, notified by the kext, has an event handler associated with it and when the application terminates, you get called back in the registered functions *process_termination_event* and *process_termination_finalize*

Whilst this method requires an associated user-level daemon application with the kext, that's not such a bad thing from a security and stability point of view.

Comment: The approach is good. But I'm stuck with a "application WILL terminate" problem. Because the kext function keep the app alive. The app is not able to terminate until the kext finished processing.

Comment: If you've implemented what I've described, there should be no problem with the app terminating - I use this all the time. The kernel extension is doing nothing more than notifying the daemon of process activity, it should not be holding any resources of the process.

Comment: I think I implemented as described. Now I added a more detailed description and the daemon code. Maybe there is something wrong or the kext processing (while loop / lock) does not fit to the intention at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the while loop in the kernel extension. Anyhow, if you have Amit Singh's book, Mac OS X Internals, it has a full example of how to write the kernel extension for monitoring VNode activity, which fits in with the answer I have provided. I suggest taking a look at that. If you don't have it and you're doing any low level OS X code, I recommend you buy it; while a little outdated, it's invaluable.

Comment: Merlin069, could you imagine to help me with the code? I do not want that for free! But I think of that issue I get gray hair... I created a complete sample project, marked with the issue position...

Comment: Where is the "complete sample project"?

Comment: Sorry, but I will not download a zip file. If you want to provide code, please use a site such as pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ and provide the link.

Comment: Sorry, I did not think about. The same problem exist in Apples TcpLogNke. I need someones help, who can implement a larger "data out" delay, so that e.g. firefox will not be able to detach the socket while waiting. Could you give me a trash mail account for contact data exchange?